# R loops and data.frame

Tags: r, algorithm, k-means

A part of the code is

```
sse <-c()                         
k <- c()    

for (i in seq(3, 15, 1)) {                        

  y_pred <-knn(train = newdata.training, test = newdata.test,
               cl = newdata.trainLabels, k=i)

  pred_y <- as.numeric(levels(y_pred)[y_pred])            
  sse[i] <- sum((newdata.trainLabels-pred_y)^2)   

  k[i] <- i                                
}
```

`pred_y` is a column for each `i`. I want to create a data frame with all the 13 columns. Can it be done by using a `for` loop? Or else how can this be accomplished? I need suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `foreach` which has the added advantage that it can be run in parallel if you have multiple cores in your CPU.  Here is the non-parallel code:

```
library("iterators")
library("foreach")
library("FNN")

data(iris3)
newdata.training <- rbind(iris3[1:25,,1], iris3[1:25,,2], iris3[1:25,,3])
newdata.test <- rbind(iris3[26:50,,1], iris3[26:50,,2], iris3[26:50,,3])
newdata.trainlabels <- factor(c(rep(1,25), rep(2,25), rep(3,25)))

k.values = seq(3, 15, 1)
start = 2  # to index sse array using k.values
sse = numeric(length = length(k.values))
results = foreach(i = iter(k.values),.combine = cbind) %do%
{
  y_pred <-knn(train = newdata.training, test = newdata.test,
               cl = newdata.trainlabels, k=i, prob = TRUE)

  pred_y <- as.numeric(levels(y_pred)[y_pred])            
  sse[i - start] <- sum((as.numeric(newdata.trainlabels)-pred_y)^2) 
  pred_y 
}

results1 = data.frame(results)
colnames(results1) = k.values
```

Here is the parallel version:

```
# Parallel version
library("iterators")
library("foreach")
library("parallel")
library("doParallel")
library("FNN")


data(iris3)
newdata.training <- rbind(iris3[1:25,,1], iris3[1:25,,2], iris3[1:25,,3])
newdata.test <- rbind(iris3[26:50,,1], iris3[26:50,,2], iris3[26:50,,3])
newdata.trainlabels <- factor(c(rep(1,25), rep(2,25), rep(3,25)))

num.cores = detectCores()
clusters <- makeCluster(num.cores)
registerDoParallel(clusters)
k.values = seq(3, 15, 1)
start = 2  # to index sse array using k.values
sse = numeric(length = length(k.values))
results = foreach(i = iter(k.values),.combine = cbind, .packages=c("FNN")) %dopar%
{
  y_pred <-knn(train = newdata.training, test = newdata.test,
               cl = newdata.trainlabels, k=i, prob = TRUE)

  pred_y <- as.numeric(levels(y_pred)[y_pred])            
  sse[i - start] <- sum((as.numeric(newdata.trainlabels)-pred_y)^2) 
  pred_y 
}

results1 = data.frame(results)
colnames(results1) = k.values
stopCluster(clusters)
```

There are only a few differences between the non-parallel code and the parallel code.  First, there are additional libraries to load.  Second, you need to create and register the clusters that will do the parallel computation (and stop the clusters when you are done).  Third, `foreach` uses `%dopar%` infix operator instead of `%do%`.  Fourth, the `foreach` function needs the `.packages` parameter to pass `KNN` to each of the clusters.

Comment: is the package `knn` or `fnn`?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor It's FNN: Fast Nearest Neighbor algorithms http://www.cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/FNN.pdf